# Add password protection while converting HTML to MS Word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ms-word, converters

I have generated an MS Word file from HTML using Jquery, but i need to add password protection to this file. Is there is any metadata to set a password before generatinga file?

Reference: https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/jQuery-Plugin-To-Save-Webpage-As-MS-Word-Document-Googoose.html

Code is from the library.

```
var html = '<html xmlns:o=\'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\' xmlns:w=\'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\' xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\'>\n';
            html += '<head> <meta charset=\'utf-8\'>\n';
            html += '<!--[if gte mso 9]>\n';
            html += '<xml>\n';
            html += '<w:WordDocument>\n';
            html += ( '<w:View>' + options.display + '</w:View>\n' );
            html += ('<w:Zoom>'+ options.zoom +'</w:Zoom>\n');
            html += '<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>\n';
            html += '</w:WordDocument>\n';
            html += '<o:OfficeDocumentSettings>\n';
            html += '<o:AllowPNG/>\n';
            html +='</o:OfficeDocumentSettings>\n';
            html += '</xml>\n';
            html += '<![endif]-->\n';
            html += '';
//close head
            html += '</head>\n';

//Adding page content here 

 html + = '<body><div><p>Hai</p>';

 //close body
 html += '</div></body>\n';

  //close doc
 html += '</html>\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

There no such option in googoose library.

For your reference,

https://github.com/aadel112/googoose#user-content-options.

Setting a password to file is not supported by JS or Jquery.

But I have seen setting a password for pdf using adobe extensions.

If you definitely want to set password then  I would recommend you to move the logic to server side  and use any server side library for setting password.

Comment: How to make it support by the plugin?

Comment: There was a typo. It is not supported by the plugin. Read only is something to do with operating system.